# retrieve data from multiple tables in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

i am using cakephp 2.xx. i have two tables in my database names and genders. i write innerjoin to display names with their gender. gender is coming from genders table. my controller is below

```
class NamesController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array("Html", "Form");
public function index() {
    $this->loadModel("names");
$query_options = array();
$query_options["fields"] = array("names.Name","genders.gender");
$query_options["joins"] = array("table" => "genders", "alias" => "genders", "type" => "INNER", "conditions" => array("genders.id = names.Gender_id",));
$this->set("gender", $this->names->find('all', array($query_options,'limit' => 10 ,'recursive' => 1)));
}
}
```

names model is

```
class Names extends AppModel {  
     var $belongsTo = 'Genders';     
}
```

and genders model is

```
class Genders extends AppModel {    
    var $hasMany = 'Names';
    }
```

and ctp code is

```
foreach ($gender as $post);
echo $post["names"]["Name"];
echo $post["genders"]["gender"];
```

this print Name fine. but doesn't print gender and result in Undefined index: genders. Please help

Comment: Use joins if you need child table conditions. Use contain to retrieve child tables data. Use both when needed. :)

Comment: i use joins and contain individually and separately but same result

Comment: Check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation, you don't have to follow it: Use singular names for models (Name, Gender). This way it will automatically connect with the appropriate table (names, genders) and your models will be loaded automatically in their controllers (NamesController, GendersController). If you don't follow this advice, change the code below accordingly (load the model manually as you did in your question and set $useTable in the model).

*Option 1: getting all names containing gender data:*

```
class NamesController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $this->Name->Behaviors->load('Containable');
        $query_options = array(
            'fields' => array("Name.name"),
            'contain' => array(
                'Gender' => array(
                    'fields' => array('Gender.gender'),
                ),
            ),
        );
        $this->set("names", $this->Name->find('all', $query_options));
    }
}
```

*Option 2: getting genders containing all names that belong to them:*

```
class NamesController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $this->Name->Gender->Behaviors->load('Containable');
        $query_options = array(
            'fields' => array("Gender.gender"),
            'contain' => array(
                'Name' => array(
                    'fields' => array('Name.name'),
                ),
            ),
        );
        $this->set("genders", $this->Name->Gender->find('all', $query_options));
    }
}
```

Use debug($names) or debug($genders) in your view to see the output array structure.

Comment: i tried option 1 and 2 but same result. how can i apply singular names. i have wrote only one controller namescontroller. there is no other genedercontrollers. is there need to write another if yes then how. Thanks

Comment: That was just a recommendation, it will work without it... It means when you have a `names` table and a `genders` table, you can access the `Gender` model and use its model functions without even defining that model. It's how Cake works. But that is irrelevant to your question. Can you debug the output you get and post the results?